# vue-cli3 Could not proxy request

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

when I run **npm run start**, I get

```
start": "vue-cli-service serve"
```

and then I use http request, but I get

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /crm/api/boss/admin/doLogin from
>   localhost:8080 to https://qa6boss.qjdchina.com. See
>   https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for
>   more information (EPROTO).

What is the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by changing the target from http://localhost:8000/ to http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Answer (score 1):

```
'^/api': { 
   target: 'http://localhost:3000', 
   changeOrigin: true, enter code here
   secure: false, 
   pathRewrite: {
     '^/api': '/api'
   }, 
   headers: {
     Connection: 'keep-alive'
   }
 },
```

Comment: Please provider more details on the case. What produced this error and more details on your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add pathRewrite e.g.:

```
'^/api': { 
  target: 'http://localhost:3000', 
  changeOrigin: true, 
  secure: false, 
  pathRewrite: {
    '^/api': '/api'
  }, 
  logLevel: 'debug' 
},
```